# \setcitestyle no longer working

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, natbib

I used to change the citation style in my documents using the bloc of commands:

```
\usepackage[square,authoryear]{natbib}
\setcitestyle{notesep={:},aysep={}}
\usepackage{chapterbib}
```

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,final,onecolumn,thmsb,titlepage]{book}
\usepackage[square,authoryear]{natbib}
\setcitestyle{notesep={:},aysep={}}
\usepackage{chapterbib}
\begin{document}
\citet[22]{Draa2019} states that ...
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
{\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\bibliography{thebib2}}
\end{document}
```

the bib file contant is the following

```
@article{Draa2019, 
title={{The Impact of Translation on Reading Comprehension for EST Learners - A Case Study of Computer Science Students at Constantine 2 University}}, 
volume={51},
journal={{Revue Sciences Humaines}},
author={Draa, A.}, 
pages={135 --150 },
year={2019},}
```

I wanted to replace the comma separating the author from the year with the space, and to replace the comma of the note (page number) with a colon.

But, this is no longer working, maybe due to an update of bibtex/natbib versions.

Any help please?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Could you try and see if `\setcitestyle{authoryear}
` helps?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please clarify what you mean by "`\setcitestyle` no longer working". For sure, if I compile your test document, `citet[22]{Draa2019}` produces "Draa [2019:22]", while `\citep{Draa2019}` produces "[Draa 2019]". Both are *exactly* what one would expect from `\setcitestyle{notesep={:},aysep={}}`.

Comment: @Mico: Exactly, this is what I wanted and used to get as result, Draa [2019:22], but it is not working, I get the error message: "Undefined control sequence. \setcitestyle". I will edit the question to become more specific. Thanks.

Comment: @AmerDraa - The command `\setcitestyle` is provided by the `natbib` package. As long as `natbib` is loaded properly, `\setcitestyle` should work too.

Comment: @Mico - Thank you again, I could solve the issue by replacing the natbib package with an older version (I renamed it and placed it in the same folder). I think, it is a version issue, I recently upgraded to texlive 2021, since then these issues occur from time to time. Thank you another time.

Comment: @AmerDraa - I use TeXLive2021 as well (actually, MacTeX2021) and `natbib 2010/09/13 8.31b`. The `natbib` package has remained unchanged for the past 11 years. Not sure what you mean by "an older version of `natbib`".

Comment: @Mico - I just compared the two .sty files; that installed on my 2021 texlive folder is an old one:  [2003/06/06 7.1 (PWD)], while that which solved the problem is a newer one: [2010/09/13 8.31b (PWD, AO)]. The folowing commands, among others, are missing from the former file: % Defining the citation mode and punctual (citation style)
98 %   \setcitestyle{<comma-separated list of keywords, same 99  %     as the package options>} 100 % Example: \setcitestyle{square,semicolon} 101 % Alternatively:.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking,

The package installed in texlive 2021 does not cause bugs; it seems that the 'natbib.sty' file has been previously replaced by an older version. It is likely I did when trying to solve other issues or doing other adjustments.

Sorry for the inconvenience and thank you to everyone.